# Using ModelBuilder and iteration to calculate values from previous row?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I would like to come up with a model that takes the previous value and adds it to the current value.

For instance

Value
3, 2, 3, 1

Would result in

-, 5, 5, 4

I have been trying to use Iterate Field Values and Calculate Field, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any tips? Would it be easier to add the current value to the *next* value?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would try and use python in field calculator to achieve the desired result:

`accumulate( !HA! )`

Pre logic script code:

```
total = 0
```

`previous = 0
def accumulate(increment):
 global previous
 global total
 if total:
  total = increment + previous
  previous = increment
 else:
  total = increment
  previous = increment
 return total`